# Celery, RabbitMQ and heroku

Tags: django, heroku, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I am a newbie on Celery. I have been trying to use RabbitMq as a broker for celery in django. I am using django-celery as well. Add on I am using that is provided by heroku for RabbitMQ is `CloudAMQP Little Lemur (Free)`. Things arer working fine.

But I am confused about `kombu` and `amqp` logs that I see. Yes they are installed but are not used.

```
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864214+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 278, in start
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864212+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864197+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2015-05-13 05:39:06,857: WARNING/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864216+00:00 app[worker.1]:     blueprint.start(self)
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864219+00:00 app[worker.1]:     step.start(parent)
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864218+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 123, in start
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864222+00:00 app[worker.1]:     c.loop(*c.loop_args())
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864220+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 821, in start
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864223+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 70, in asynloop
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864225+00:00 app[worker.1]:     next(loop)
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864226+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/async/hub.py", line 324, in create_loop
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864229+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/base.py", line 162, in on_readable
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864230+00:00 app[worker.1]:     reader(loop)
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864232+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/base.py", line 144, in _read
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864233+00:00 app[worker.1]:     drain_events(timeout=0)
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864234+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 323, in drain_events
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864235+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return amqp_method(channel, args)
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864228+00:00 app[worker.1]:     cb(*cbargs)
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864237+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 1646, in _basic_cancel_notify
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864238+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise ConsumerCancelled(consumer_tag, (60, 30))
2015-05-13T05:39:06.864239+00:00 app[worker.1]: ConsumerCancelled: Basic.cancel: (0) 4
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987183+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2015-05-13 05:39:36,986: WARNING/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987189+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987191+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 278, in start
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987194+00:00 app[worker.1]:     blueprint.start(self)
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987195+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 123, in start
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987200+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 70, in asynloop
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987202+00:00 app[worker.1]:     next(loop)
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987198+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 821, in start
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987199+00:00 app[worker.1]:     c.loop(*c.loop_args())
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987204+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/async/hub.py", line 324, in create_loop
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987207+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/base.py", line 162, in on_readable
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987205+00:00 app[worker.1]:     cb(*cbargs)
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987208+00:00 app[worker.1]:     reader(loop)
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987196+00:00 app[worker.1]:     step.start(parent)
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987210+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/base.py", line 144, in _read
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987212+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 323, in drain_events
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987211+00:00 app[worker.1]:     drain_events(timeout=0)
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987216+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise ConsumerCancelled(consumer_tag, (60, 30))
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987214+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return amqp_method(channel, args)
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987215+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 1646, in _basic_cancel_notify
2015-05-13T05:39:36.987218+00:00 app[worker.1]: ConsumerCancelled: Basic.cancel: (0) 8
```

**settings.py**

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://xxxx:xxx@xxxx/xxx'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json', 'msgpack', 'yaml']
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djcelery',
)
```

**proj/celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**someapp/tasks.py**

```
from celery import task
#Also import User model
@task()
def add(x,y):
    User.objects.create(name='ccc')
```

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn proj.wsgi
worker: python manage.py celery worker
```